# INotifyPropertyChanged Disable Button and CheckBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, inotifypropertychanged

I am using the following command to update the button on GUI

`PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(resetButton.IsEnabled = false));`

However, I get an error `

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'string'

**EDIT**

This XAML code for the button that I want to disable when its clicked.

`resetButton.IsEnabled = false` is what I initially tried to use to disable it.

```
<Button x:Name="resetButton"
        Grid.Row="1" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
        Width="80" 
        Content="Reset" 
        Style="{StaticResource BlueButton}"
        Click="resetButton_Click"/>
```

Comment: The PropertyChangedEventArgs constructor takes a string as a parameter, where the string is the name of the property that was updated. The name should be of a property in the class that inherits INotifyPropertyChanged. and then resetButton.IsEnabled is bound to that in XAML.

Answer (score -1):

I will first discuss the mere syntactical error that the compiler is complaining about:

You invoke

```
new PropertyChangedEventArgs(resetButton.IsEnabled = false)
```

In there, the expression

```
resetButton.IsEnabled = false
```

will evaluate to a `bool`. Hence, you are passing a `bool` to the constructor of [`PropertyChangedEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventargs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

However, [that constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventargs.propertychangedeventargs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) expects a `string`, namely the name of the changed property.

---

Now, concerning the intended result:

> I am using the following command to update the button on GUI

No, you are not. At least, not directly.

What you *can* use the call to `PropertyChanged` for is to fire any event handlers registered with the `PropertyChanged` event, which can then do whatever you want them to do, e.g. update something in the GUI.

Therefore, somewhere else in the code, you have to write something like this:

```
myObject.PropertyChanged += delegate(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    resetButton.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

This creates an anonymous method and registers it as an event handler with your event.

Now, *usually*, you will also want to check the [`PropertyName` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventargs.propertyname(v=vs.100).aspx) on the `e` argument to see *which* property of `myObject` has actually been changed.

And here, we get back to your firing of the event: You have to pass in the property name of the changed property upon constructing the `PropertyChangedEventArgs` instance.

*If* your property is of type `bool` (or if you have an appropriate [value converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to convert whatever type your property is to `bool`), you can also directly bind the `resetButton.IsEnabled` property in XAML to your property. It will then automatically register a handler with the `PropertyChanged` event under the hood in order to update the enabled state of the button when required.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation which makes sense. However, I am new to XAML, cant figure out the whole syntax. I'd appreciate if you could put it as one piece.

Comment: I considered adding a XAML fragment that shows the button with the binding, too ... but for that, I'd need to know what's your property (that you are firing `PropertyChanged` for) is called.

Comment: The question still does not contain any hint as to how the property that you are binding to is named. You do have a property on your object from where you are firing the `PropertyChanged` event, right?

Comment: To whoever downvoted this answer, may I ask what could be improved about it?

Comment: I am new to XAML/C#, so I am not quite sure if I understand it fully. Could you please give an example about that property or hint that I can look for. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Imsa: About which property? I think some more of your code is required to provide some specific help beyond showing a generic example for a property binding or of using `INotifyPropertyChanged` (of which there are plenty online).

Comment: You should avoid `+=` events here. The proper route is to use either Command-Binding with a CanExecute member or bind in MVVM style to a CanReset boolean property.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Why? What is wrong about registering with an event via `+=`? Also, note that the binding route is already described in the final paragraph of the answer.